# MySQL Regexp find href with space at the end

Tags: html, mysql, regex

There is a column in a MySQL table that stores HTML code.

Unfortunately some link hrefs end with a space like

```
...some code...<a href="/path/further-path/and-more-path "...>some-text</a>...some code...
```

Now I have to find each column row that have such a link in its content column.

Tried some regexp select:

```
content REGEXP '.+href="[a-zA-Z0-9/\-][[:space:]]".+'
content REGEXP '.+href="[a-zA-Z0-9/\-]( )".+'
```

With and without the .+ but none of them find anything that fits.
I am sure that there are entries containing such links ;).

Please help. I am not a regex guru at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `+` quantifier:

```
content REGEXP '.+href="[a-zA-Z0-9/\-]+[[:space:]]".+'
#                              here __^
```